# the header is not displayed in red color

Tags: html, css

I would like to obtain this type of result in HTML/CSS:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ku2cy.png)

The header is in red color, but I don't display it in my result below...

[my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1Y8g.png)

How could I display the color in red, please?I think I missed a step?

Here's a reproduction if you want in [CSS/HTML](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-y6ujfr?file=src/app/views/dashboard/dashboard.component.html)

Thank you very much for your help concerning my problem.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
@import url(https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css);
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
    background-color: #2af598;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif, Verdana, Tahoma;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

h1 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 50px 0;
}


/* MENU - SIDEBAR */


/* C'est le fond bleu vertical */

.sidebar {
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #fff;
    /*#239cd3;*/
    height: 781px;
}


/* C'est le logo */

.sidebar .logo-details {
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}


/* Centraliser les rubriques */

.sidebar .menu {
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 45px;
    color: #4d4d4d;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}


/* Ajustage icones  */

.sidebar li i {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.2rem;
    left: 1rem;
    color: #595959;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}


/* Placer les flèches à droite */

.sidebar li i.fa-chevron-down {
    right: 1rem;
    left: auto;
}


/* Pivoter en haut / en bas la flèche */

.sidebar li.active i.fa-chevron-down {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}


/* Changement de couleur de la rubrique après clique */

.sidebar li.active .menu {
    color: #b63b4d;
}


/* Changement de couleur icones après clique */

.sidebar li.active i {
    color: #b63b4d;
}


/* Adaptation fond pour le sous menu */

.submenu {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #fff;
    /* #239cd3;*/
    font-size: 14px;
    transition: height 0.4s ease;
}


/* Ligne de séparateur sur chaque submenu */

.submenu li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #4b4a5e;
}


/* Sous-menu après cliquage */

.submenu a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: blue;
    padding: 12px;
    padding-left: 42px;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
}


/* Survole submenu en couleur */

.submenu a:hover {
    background: #b63b4d;
    color: #fff;
}


/* Header */

.header {
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0 0 0 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
    <div class="logo-details"> </div>
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let menu of menus; let i = index" [class.active]="menu.active">
            <ng-container>
                <div class="menu" (click)="selectMenu(menu)">
                    <i [class]="menu.iconClass"></i> {{ menu.name }}
                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
                </div>
                <ul class="submenu" #submenu [ngStyle]="{ 'height': menu.active ? submenu.scrollHeight + 'px' : 0 + 'px' }">
                    <li *ngFor="let submenu of menu.submenu">
                        <a routerLink="{{ submenu.url }}"> {{ submenu.name }} </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </ng-container>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="header">
    <div>text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your header class:

```
.header {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
}
```

With `top: 0` you are taking the div to the top and with `position: absolute` you are forcing to take the `top: 0` position

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't that the background isn't displaying in red (it is red in your stackblitz code), your problem is that you don't really have any sort of wrapper div to give your sidebar/header divs any positioning context. If you have a wrapper parent div and set it to flex, your header should probably position itself accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you've put the background color for all the body of your HTML file instead of applying it to the div that contain the section you want either red or green.

Answer (score 0):

there's a couple of solutions that I can think of right now, the best one and easiest one I could think of is to make the header above the navbar in your code and then change the CSS accordingly.

## HTML

```
<div class="header">
  <div>qzzz</div>
</div>
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="logo-details"></div>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let menu of menus; let i = index" [class.active]="menu.active">
      <ng-container>
        <div class="menu" (click)="selectMenu(menu)">
          <i [class]="menu.iconClass"></i> {{ menu.name }}
          <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
        </div>
        <ul
          class="submenu"
          #submenu
          [ngStyle]="{
            height: menu.active ? submenu.scrollHeight + 'px' : 0 + 'px'
          }"
        >
          <li *ngFor="let submenu of menu.submenu">
            <a routerLink="{{ submenu.url }}"> {{ submenu.name }} </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </ng-container>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

## CSS: replace this margin inside your header class

```
margin: 0 0 0 20%;
```